# How to open and modify values in an excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan, xlrd, xlwt

Some values in an excel file have an extra `'='` character which makes them be shown as `NaN values` when the file is imported as a Dataframe in python, and they should be modified before importing.
How can I remove the `'='` character in values using python?
For instance, I want to change `=-FDGBJT-R54RET8-Y4W5KJGJF`  to  `-FDGBJT-R54RET8-Y4W5KJGJF` .

Comment: Did you manually specify the datatypes of each column, or are you letting Pandas determine it automatically? You should be able to manually set a column to the "string" dtype on the `pd.read_excel()` function call, which might avoid the interpretation of the `=` character. Let me know if that helps or if you've already tried it.

Comment: In Excel, is the value being read as a formula? That is, the one with the `=` at the beginning, does Excel display it with the `=` or does it just display all characters after the `=`? I just made an excel file where cell A1 was your first value (with the equals) and cell A2 was the second value (same string without the equals). They are both a 'general' data type in Excel, and the cell A1 displays the equals sign (so it isn't a formula, it is fully a string). When I do pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',headers=None), it reads both values the exact same as in Excel. That is, it reads it right.